# Video first frame is always there above the video in exoplayer. How to remove if when video playing?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, exoplayer

I am playing video in exoplayer but an image which seems like thumb nail appears above the video for all the time. I don't know what is this. I think this is a first frame of video. It only appears on some devices. If you have a solution please guide. Thanks in advance.

Below is the Screen Short of my problem.[image]

Below is my xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_relative"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
            android:id="@+id/vv_clips"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_200sdp" />

        <com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/shimmer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_60sdp"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_4sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/dark_grey" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_40sdp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp">

            <Chronometer
                android:id="@+id/video_counter"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="00:00"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_timer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="00:00"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_white"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:typeface="@string/text_semi_bold_display" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_60sdp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/play_linear"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="22dp"
                    android:layout_height="22dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/play" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_play"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/video_play_text"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark_white"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    app:typeface="@string/text_semi_bold_display" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="22dp"
                    android:layout_height="22dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/share_new"
                    app:tint="@color/dark_white" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/share"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark_white"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    app:typeface="@string/text_semi_bold_display" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/likeLinear"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/favourite"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/favourite_check_cuts"
                    android:stateListAnimator="@animator/scale" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/like_text"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark_white"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    app:typeface="@string/text_semi_bold_display" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_55sdp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_12sdp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Video Title"
                android:paddingStart="5dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_white"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_white"
                android:padding="7dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                android:text="Description"
                android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme"
                app:typeface="@string/text_regular_display" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_indicator"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_40sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_45sdp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_up"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to clear the surface when player state ready but no luck.